# how can I build older version of gcc?

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, gcc

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.2 32 bit platform and I have  gcc 4.8.4 installed. I want to build old version of gcc (2.95.3) to compile older version of linux kernel. I tried to follow this [gcc-2.95.3](http://tldp.org/LDP/lfs/5.0/html/chapter06/gcc-2953.html) and this [gcc-2.95.3-64](http://www.trevorpounds.com/blog/?p=111) (though the latter instructs how to build 32 bit of gcc in 64 bit host, it seems helpful but didn't work) guides but I failed to build it.
Is there a way to compile it in my current distro?

EDIT: Here is the error message I get using `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc --sysconfdir=/etc`
and `make bootstrap` If I don't use **bootstrap** flag I get more errors before reaching below errors. Below error messages are from `gcc-2.95.1`

```
Making info file `cpp.info' from `./cpp.texi'.
./cpp.texi:2041: Unknown command `sam'.
./cpp.texi:2041: Misplaced {.
./cpp.texi:2041: Misplaced }.
./cpp.texi:2041: Unmatched }.
./cpp.texi:361: Node `Include Operation''s Next field not pointed back to.
./cpp.texi:421: This node (`Once-Only') is the one with the bad `Prev'.
./cpp.texi:815: Next reference to nonexistent node `Nonstandard Predefined'.
./cpp.texi:802: `Standar Predefiined' has an Up field of `Predefined', but `Predefined' has no menu item for `Standar Predefiined'.
./cpp.texi:998: Prev reference to nonexistent node `Standard Predefined'.
./cpp.texi:802: `Nonstanard Preddefined' has an Up field of `Predefined', but `Predefined' has no menu item for `Nonstanard Preddefined'.
./cpp.texi:1366: Next reference to nonexistent node `Macro Parentheses'.
./cpp.texi:1398: Node `Macro Prenthesees''s Next field not pointed back to.
./cpp.texi:1475: This node (`SwallowSemicoloon') is the one with the bad `Prev'.
./cpp.texi:1398: Node `Macro Prenthesees's Prev field not pointed back to.
./cpp.texi:1366: This node (`Misnesting') has the bad Next.
./cpp.texi:1342: `Macro Prenthesees' has an Up field of `Macro Pitfalls', but `Macro Pitfalls' has no menu item for `Macro Prenthesees'.
./cpp.texi:1475: Node `SwallowSemicoloon''s Next field not pointed back to.
./cpp.texi:1538: This node (`Side Effects') is the one with the bad `Prev'.
./cpp.texi:1342: `SwallowSemicoloon' has an Up field of `Macro Pitfalls', but `Macro Pitfalls' has no menu item for `SwallowSemicoloon'.
./cpp.texi:1342: `Argumen Prescann' has an Up field of `Macro Pitfalls', but `Macro Pitfalls' has no menu item for `Argumen Prescann'.
./cpp.texi:1812: Next reference to nonexistent node `Newline in Argss'.
./cpp.texi:1850: Node `Newlines in Args's Prev field not pointed back to.
./cpp.texi:1812: This node (`Cascaded Macros') has the bad Next.
./cpp.texi:1911: Node `Conditinal Usess' missing Up field.
./cpp.texi:1944: Next reference to nonexistent node `Deleted ode'.
./cpp.texi:1944: Prev reference to nonexistent node `Conditioal Usess'.
./cpp.texi:1959: Next reference to nonexistent node `#else Diective.'.
./cpp.texi:2018: Node `#else Directive' missing Up field.
./cpp.texi:2039: Node `#elif Directive' missing Up field.
./cpp.texi:2086: Node `Deleted Code' missing Up field.
./cpp.texi:2107: Node `Conditionals-Macros' missing Up field.
./cpp.texi:2208: Next reference to nonexistent node `#error Directive'.
./cpp.texi:2208: Prev reference to nonexistent node `Conditioals-Maccros'.
./cpp.texi:2338: Node `#error irectivee' missing Up field.
./cpp.texi:71: `Other Drectivess' has an Up field of `Top', but `Top' has no menu item for `Other Drectivess'.
./cpp.texi:2435: Cross reference to nonexistent node `Standard Predefined'.
./cpp.texi:2360: Cross reference to nonexistent node `Nonstandard Predefined'.
./cpp.texi:1956: Menu reference to nonexistent node `#elif Diective.'.
./cpp.texi:1955: Menu reference to nonexistent node `#else Diective.'.
./cpp.texi:1908: Menu reference to nonexistent node `#error Directive'.
./cpp.texi:1906: Menu reference to nonexistent node `Conditioals-Maccros'.
./cpp.texi:1905: Menu reference to nonexistent node `Deleted ode'.
./cpp.texi:1903: Menu reference to nonexistent node `Conditioal Usess'.
./cpp.texi:1360: Menu reference to nonexistent node `Argument Prescan'.
./cpp.texi:1355: Menu reference to nonexistent node `Swallow Semicolon'.
./cpp.texi:1353: Menu reference to nonexistent node `Macro Parentheses'.
./cpp.texi:1148: Cross reference to nonexistent node `Swallow Semicolon'.
./cpp.texi:812: Menu reference to nonexistent node `Nonstandard Predefined'.
./cpp.texi:811: Menu reference to nonexistent node `Standard Predefined'.
./cpp.texi:128: Menu reference to nonexistent node `Other Directives'.
./cpp.texi:815: warning: unreferenced node `Standar Predefiined'.
./cpp.texi:998: warning: unreferenced node `Nonstanard Preddefined'.
./cpp.texi:1398: warning: unreferenced node `Macro Prenthesees'.
./cpp.texi:1911: warning: unreferenced node `Conditinal Usess'.
./cpp.texi:2018: warning: unreferenced node `#else Directive'.
./cpp.texi:2039: warning: unreferenced node `#elif Directive'.
./cpp.texi:2086: warning: unreferenced node `Deleted Code'.
./cpp.texi:2338: warning: unreferenced node `#error irectivee'.
makeinfo: Removing output file `cpp.info' due to errors; use --force to preserve.
make[2]: *** [cpp.info] Error 2
```

Comment: can you give details on what you have done and how it failed?

Comment: Is installing a virtualization package (virtualbox/kvm/vmware) an option? Would use that to install the last LTS release that ran that specific gcc version. The ISOs will probably still be somewhere around.

Comment: @son_of_fire What I tried listed in the links. I get `/gcc/cpp.texi:363: Unknown command` like errors.

Comment: @JdeHaan I ll give a try live.iso or VM options if I don't get working solutions here

Comment: Do you really need GCC 2.95.x? glibc dropped support for that years ago, and uses extensions in standard headers that break with GCC 2. GCC 3.3 compiles, installs and runs without much of a problem on modern systems. If you do really need GCC 2, you'll need to install two versions of glibc side-by-side as well, your current version (overwriting that with an old version would break pretty much everything), and the old version installed in a non-standard location. But if the old version is installed in a non-standard location, you then need to patch GCC 2 to find it. It's probably not worth it.

Comment: By the way, you don't need `makeinfo` for any of the official GCC releases, the releases include pre-generated `.info` files already. The build system attempts to rebuild them if `makeinfo` is available (somewhat pointlessly), but you can trick it into thinking there is no `makeinfo` by exporting `MAKEINFO=missing` in your environment, assuming you have no program named `missing`.

Comment: @hvd 
Thank you for the info. I want to compile an older kernel (linux-2.6.23) to make a distro to fit in a floppy disk. Do you think gcc-3.3 does the job?

Comment: Yes, the 2.6.23 kernel can be built with gcc 3.3 (which is ten years old now). You can find gcc 3.3 binaries on http://snapshot.debian.org or http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-3.3/ (for Ubuntu).

Comment: @kenn Probably best to check what the supported GCC version was for that kernel, and use that. Linux 2.6.23 was released October 2007. The then-current versions of GCC were 4.1.x and 4.2.x.

Comment: @StephenKitt
Thanks. I installed these packages from that link `gcc-3.3-base_3.3.4-9ubuntu5.1_i386.deb cpp-3.3_3.3.4-9ubuntu5.1_i386.deb gcc-3.3_3.3.4-9ubuntu5.1_i386.deb` Which other packages do I need to install? More important one, where is gcc installed?

Comment: That should be enough; gcc should be available as `/usr/bin/gcc-3.3`.

Comment: @StephenKitt Thank you. I ll try to build the kernel now.

Comment: @StephenKitt
I keep getting 
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`
errors in gcc-3.3 I issued `gcc-3.3 -print-search-dirs` and symlinked crt1.o directory to its searchpath but whatever I did I could not fix it.

Comment: @StephenKitt
I'm sorry, it's my fault. I fixed it copying files to search path of gcc-3.3. As to building of kernel nothing changed. I get the same errors as in gcc-4.8

Comment: @kenn even with @hvd's fix for `makeinfo`?

Comment: I haven't tried it in a clean source  code yet.

Comment: @StephenKitt My comment about `makeinfo` was about building GCC, not about using it to build the kernel. The question has now radically changed, as the OP has simply given up on building GCC, and is instead using pre-built packages. There are no details in the question or comments about problems compiling the kernel with either a new version of GCC or an old one, and I don't think it would be right to include them, as they would invalidate the existing answers. To the OP: if you have problems building a specific Linux version, I recommend posting a new question asking only how to solve that.

Comment: @hvd Oops, yes, I got mixed up there...

Comment: Very probably, compiling a very old kernel with a recent compiler should work (perhaps you should lower the optimization level from `-O2` to `-O1` but that is not a big deal). And you should explain why you want to compile such an old kernel. Kernels are compatibles with older versions.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch
Thank you for commenting. I checked out your profile, you must be a master. I hope your solution work. I want to compile an older kernel  to make it fit in a floppy disk to test it in qemu. I wanted to realize the tutorial in following link http://www.slitaz.org/en/doc/scratchbook/base-system.html

Answer (score 5):

You'll have a hard time building such an old version of gcc on a modern system... The errors you've copied are from `texinfo`, which is no longer compatible with the documentation included in gcc 2.95.

You can try installing binaries straight from http://snapshot.debian.org/package/gcc-2.95/2.95.4.ds15-27/; installing `cpp-2.95` and `gcc-2.95` from there will give you C support without touching your existing installation of gcc. To get C++ support you'd need `g++-2.95` and the libraries; I haven't checked to see how well they'd install on a modern system.

Comment: Thank you for your practical answer. It's easier than running a VM.

Answer (score 2):

I've just finished installing gcc-3.4.6 and gcc-2.95.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 using the steps from the following [tutorial](http://www.trevorpounds.com/blog/?p=111). It doesn't make much sense for me to post the steps here because you also need to download some patch files from that page.

For both compilations I had to add `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0` to the `CFLAGS` in all the Makefile from the gcc build directory and its subfolders that contain other Makefiles.

I needed to first install gcc-3.4.6 and then use it to build gcc-2.95.3. To do that you need to set `CC=/opt/x86_64/gcc/gcc-3.4.6/bin/gcc` in the Makefiles of gcc-2.95.3.

Additionally, I also had to copy the following files from the source directory of `glibc-2.10.1` to the `gcc-2.95.3/glibc-workaround/` directory created by the commands on the tutorial page:

- `bits/libc-lock.h`
- `sys/param.h`
- `_G_config.h`

**To fix the error message from the question above:** I commented out all the sections of the Makefiles of gcc-2.95.3 that compiled or installed `texinfo` or `cpp.info`.

Comment: Thank you posting an answer. I am glad, you proved that  example in the link works. As I pointed out in my question, I failed to build it by that tutorial. I am on Ubuntu 14.04.2 32 bit platform. Do you think 32 bit architecture makes any difference?

Comment: I suspect that a 32-bit platform would make a bit of a difference in the path names, but nothing that is a show-stopper. Regarding the error you posted: it was indeed not addressed in the tutorial. I basically had to comment out a bunch of stuff related to `cpp.info` and `texinfo` from the Makefiles.

Comment: I will give another attempt to it then post the result tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to compile the older version of gcc from source and give it a different destination directory with the prefix option.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc
```

I think the gcc configure will allow you to use your existing /etc.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc --sysconfdir=/etc
```

Comment: Thank you for your post Jeight. I already tried that. I get lots of errors, I fixed some of them but it's beyond my coverage. That's why I ask for help here.